# OnConnect event not firing when using TClientSocket inside a TThread on non-blocking mode

Tags: c++, c++builder, tthread, tclientsocket

I am trying to make use of Borlands `TClientSocket` component in non-blocking mode inside a multithreaded C++ Windows application. I am creating multiple threads (classes derived from `TThread`), each of which creates its own `TClientSocket` object. I then assign member functions of the thread class to act as event handlers for the `OnConnect`, `OnDisconnect` and `OnSocketError` events of the socket. The problem I am having here is that whenever I call the `TClientSocket::Open()` function from within the `TThread::Execute()` function, the `OnConnect` event never fires. However, When I call the `Open()` function from the VCL thread prior to the `TThread::Execute()` function getting called, all of the events fire and I can use the thread-socket combination as I would like. Now I have not read anything in documentation that says that `TClientSocket` should not be used in non-blocking mode when used inside a thread, but it appears to me that there is perhaps something wrong conceptually in the way I am trying to use this class. Borland documentation is quite poor on the subject and these components have now been deprecated so reliable information is hard to come by. Despite being deprecated I have to use them as there is no alternative in the Builder 6 package I have. Can anyone please advise me if there is a right/wrong way to use `TThread` and a non-blocking `TClientSocket` in combination. I have never had problems using it as part of the VCL thread and never had problems using TServerSocket before and I really cannot understand why some events are not firing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TClientSocket` in non-blocking mode uses a hidden window internally to receive socket events.  If you use a non-blocking `TClientSocket` in a `TThread` then you must implement a message loop inside of your `TThread::Execute()` method in order to dispatch those messages to the socket's window.  Also, being window-based, that also means that the socket messages are sent to the thread that actually creates the socket window, so you have to make sure you are opening the `TClientSocket` from inside of your `TThread::Execute()` method.

BTW, BCB6 shipped with Indy 8, which is an alternative.  You can also install an up-to-date version of Indy, or even another third-party library like ICS or Synapse.

Comment: Thanks for this answer it is very helpful. Would it be sufficient to pass the main `TApplication` pointer to my thread classes and call `ProcessMessages()` on that pointer periodically from `Execute()` or must I explcitly use `GetMessage()` , `DispatchMessage()` ?

Comment: Don't use `ProcessMessages()`, a `GetMessage()`/`DispatchMessage()` loop is fine.

Comment: Or else use `TClientSocket` in blocking mode instead, then you don't have to worry about messages at all.